# Display Wordpress Sub-category in dropdown based on the selected Parent Category

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to show the parent categories in a drop-down box and based on which parent categories are selected, their Sub Categories should appear in a separate drop-down box via an ajax call.

I've done a lot of research and came across the following article which is 100% what I need to achieve: *https://1stwebdesigner.com/implement-ajax-wordpress-themes/*

I followed it correctly but for some reason, the sub-category drop-down is always disabled.

My end goal is to have the 2 dropdowns with a submit button and have it act as a search form, display the selected sub-category posts on a separate page, this was my first step to getting there but having no luck.

I've tried changing the javascript $ to jQuery as this was giving an error the first time I used it but currently no errors on the page at all.

```html
<!-- Dropdown select box & javascript -->
<div id="content">
<?php
wp_dropdown_categories('show_count=0&selected=-1&hierarchical=1&depth=1&hide_empty=0&exclude=1&show_option_none=Main Categories&name=main_cat');
?>
<select name="sub_cat" id="sub_cat" disabled="disabled"></select>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function() {
      jQuery('#main_cat').change(function() {
        var $mainCat = jQuery('#main_cat').val();

        // call ajax
        jQuery("#sub_cat").empty();
        jQuery.ajax({
          url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
          type: 'POST',
          data: 'action=my_special_action&main_catid=' + $mainCat,

          success: function(results) {
            //  alert(results);
            jQuery("#sub_cat").removeAttr("disabled");
            jQuery("#sub_cat").append(results);
          }
        });
      });
    });
</script>

</div>
```

```html
<!-- Ajax call in function.php -->

add_action('wp_ajax_my_special_action', 'my_action_callback');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_special_action', 'my_action_callback');


function implement_ajax() {
if(isset($_POST['main_catid']))
            {
            $categories=  get_categories('child_of='.$_POST['main_catid'].'&hide_empty=0');
              foreach ($categories as $cat) {
                $option .= '<option value="'.$cat->term_id.'">';
                $option .= $cat->cat_name;
                $option .= ' ('.$cat->category_count.')';
                $option .= '</option>';
              }

              echo '<option value="-1" selected="selected">Scegli...</option>'.$option;
            die();
            } // end if
}
add_action('wp_ajax_my_special_ajax_call', 'implement_ajax');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_special_ajax_call', 'implement_ajax');//for users that are not logged in.
```

Comment: `... enabled="disabled"></select>` that attribute doesn't exist, it should be `disabled="disabled"`

Comment: @GrafiCode I've tested it as disabled but still no luck on this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In jQuery you call the action `action=my_special_action` and in functions.php the function you hook with your action is `my_action_callback` but you didn't define that function. Also, the second hook is not even triggering.

Try the below code

```
<!-- Ajax call in function.php -->
add_action('wp_ajax_my_special_action', 'my_action_callback');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_special_action', 'my_action_callback');
function my_action_callback() {
    if(isset($_POST['main_catid'])) {
        $categories = get_categories('child_of='.$_POST['main_catid'].'&hide_empty=0');
        foreach ($categories as $cat) {
            $option .= '<option value="'.$cat->term_id.'">';
            $option .= $cat->cat_name;
            $option .= ' ('.$cat->category_count.')';
            $option .= '</option>';
        }
        echo '<option value="-1" selected="selected">Scegli...</option>'.$option;
        die();
    } // end if
}
```

Learn more about [How to use ajax in WordPress](https://smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/how-to-use-ajax-in-wordpress)?

Comment: Please could you clarify your answer? Do you mean the problem is OP declared ajax hooks twice?

Comment: In jQuery you call the action `action=my_special_action` and in functions.php the function you hook with your action is `my_action_callback` but you didn't define that function. Also, the second hook is not even triggering. Try my code to see if you get the results. To learn more about How to use ajax in WordPress? check out this article (https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/how-to-use-ajax-in-wordpress/)

Comment: The above answer worked, the correct function was not hooked with the action

Comment: @AlexMcCain thanks for the explaination, could you please paste it in your answer?

Comment: @GrafiCode just need insight on whether there's a possibility to have this code work as a search function by only using the dropdowns collected information and having it displayed on WordPress's standard search results page?